# Is there an event in vb.net that gets called with winforms listbox is finished loading

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can someone tell me if there is an vb.net equivalent to the following?

```cs
listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += new EventHandler(OnGeneratorStatusChanged);


private void OnGeneratorStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)

    {
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That's not a WinForms ListBox, it's a WPF ListBox. There's nothing like that in WinForms (*something* that can notify status changes of the Items Container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB.NET equivalent of that event is that event. That's just WPF and C#. WPF and VB is still the same types and members. Your question is about the difference between WPF and Windows Forms, not C# and VB. WPF was written from the ground up with some of the limitations and failings of WinForms in mind. WinForms controls have no item generator so there's nothing to raise events.

That's basically the answer to your question as asked. You haven't told us what you're actually trying to achieve, so we can't really address how you should achieve it. That's something that you should ask, if you need to, in a different question.